# How to config Low-power Periodic Interrupt Timer (LPIT) in NXP MKE16

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I'm having trouble using it with LPIT. I want to use LPIT to blink led for 1s

I use the Usage Guide in RM then follow these steps:

• Enable the LPIT module clock;

• Reset the timer channels and registers;

• Setup timer operation in debug and doze modes and enable the module;

• Setup the channel counters operation mode to "32-bit Periodic Counter",and keep default values for the trigger source;

• Set timer period for channel 0 as 1 second;

• Enable channel0 interrupt;

• Starts the timer counting afer all configuration;

• In the channel interrupt rountine, clear the channel flag every 1 second.

I folow this steps and have a error SWD not detech, i can't load the code to the board and LED not blink

This is my code:

```
/* ==============================================================
    * Include library */
#include "MKE16Z4.h"
#include <stdint.h>
/* ==============================================================
    * Include user library */
 /* ==============================================================
    * Macro */
#define DELAY_CNT       (3000000)
#define RED_LED_PIN     (1 << 5)
#define GREEN_LED_PIN   (1 << 4)
#define BUTTON_0        (1 << 2)
 /* ==============================================================
    * Variable */
volatile uint8_t Counter = 0;
 /* ==============================================================
    * Prototype local function */
/* ==============================================================
    * Prototype global function */
void initGPIO();
void delay();
void initTimer();
/*===============================================================
    * Code */
void delay()
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < DELAY_CNT; i++)
    {
        __asm("nop");
    }
}
 void initGPIO()
{
    //enable clock PORTD PORTD
    PCC->CLKCFG[PCC_PORTB_INDEX] |= PCC_CLKCFG_CGC(1);
    PCC->CLKCFG[PCC_PORTD_INDEX] |= PCC_CLKCFG_CGC(1);
    //clear MUX
    PORTB->PCR[5] &= ~ PORT_PCR_MUX(7);
    PORTB->PCR[4] &= ~ PORT_PCR_MUX(7);
    //set mux GPIO
    PORTB->PCR[5] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1);
    PORTB->PCR[4] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1);
    //set output
    FGPIOB->PDDR |= RED_LED_PIN;
    FGPIOB->PDDR |= GREEN_LED_PIN;
    //set base value
    FGPIOB->PDOR |= RED_LED_PIN;
    FGPIOB->PDOR |= GREEN_LED_PIN;
}
 void initTimer()
{
    //enable clock LPIT
    //*(uint32_t *)0x40064304U |= 1 << 8;
    PCC->CLKCFG[PCC_LPIT0_INDEX] |= PCC_CLKCFG_CGC(1);
    PCC->CLKCFG[PCC_LPIT0_INDEX] |= PCC_CLKCFG_PCS(3);

     //Timer channels and registers are reset
    LPIT0->MCR |= LPIT_MCR_SW_RST(1);
     //Timer channels and registers are not reset
    LPIT0->MCR |= LPIT_MCR_SW_RST(0);

     // Module Clock Enable , DOZE Mode Enable Bit =0, Debug Enable Bit =1;
    LPIT0->MCR |= LPIT_MCR_DBG_EN(1) | LPIT_MCR_DOZE_EN(1) | LPIT_MCR_M_CEN(1);

     // Timer Operation Mode: 32-bit Periodic Counter
    LPIT0->CHANNEL[0].TCTRL = LPIT_TCTRL_MODE(0);

     // TVAl
    LPIT0->CHANNEL[0].TVAL = (48000000 - 1);

     // chanle 0 interrupt enable
    LPIT0->MIER |= LPIT_MIER_TIE0(1);
     //enable NVIC
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPIT0_IRQn);
     // enable the TIMER channel 0
    LPIT0->SETTEN |= LPIT_SETTEN_SET_T_EN_0(1);
}
 void LPIT0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    FGPIOB->PTOR |= RED_LED_PIN;
    delay();
    LPIT0->MSR |= LPIT_MSR_TIF0(1);
}
 void main()
{
    initGPIO();
    initTimer();
    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```